# How many times must I repeat a trial to have confidence in a true result?

Tags: probability-distributions

How can I calculate the number of times I need to repeat an independent test with a probability (p) in order to have 99% confidence that I will have at least 1 true result?

Example:
I have a task that has a 20% chance of succeeding (p=0.2). How many times should I expect to repeat the task before I can be reasonably (99%) sure of a successful outcome?

Comment: Check out the binomial distribution, and ideas about Bernouli trials:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of at least one true result is one minus the probability of no true results in $n$ trials.  The probability of getting exactly $k$ sucesses in $n$ trials with probability $p$ is given by the binomial probability mass function
$$
f(k;n,p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$

$$
P(\text{at least 1 success}) = 1-P(\text{exactly 0 sucesses}) = 1-f(0;n,p)
$$
$$
f(0;n,p) = (1-p)^{n}
$$
Set that equal to $0.99$ for $99\%$, plug in your $p$, and you'll see that you go up in $n$ until $f(0;n,p)$ is less than $0.01$.  If you want a closed form expression, call the confidence as $\alpha$:

$$
P(\text{at least 1 success}) = \alpha
$$
$$
1-(1-p)^{n} = \alpha
$$
$$
(1-p)^{n} = 1-\alpha
$$
$$
\log\left((1-p)^{n}\right) = \log(1-\alpha)
$$
$$
n\log\left(1-p\right) =\log(1-\alpha)
$$
$$
n=\frac{\log(1-\alpha)}{\log\left(1-p\right)}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I need.

Comment: In the line `(at least 1 success)=` shouldn't this be `(at least 1 success)>=`? We want to find n such that p(given n) >= alpha